# OBIEE 12c. Creating custom link in header with privilege in XML

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c, obiee

```
<link id="l3" name="LInkName" description="Desc" src="URL" target="blank" iconSmall="common/info_ena.png" >
       <locations>
          <location name="header" insertBefore="home"/>
       </locations>
    </link>
```

I need to add here restriction by privilege, this link must be do not display if user have no BIServiceAdministrator role.

I checked this in Oracle help, but there just:

link: privilege
Optional
String
Specifies the name of privileges that a user must be granted to see the link. The privileges are indicated as an expression, as shown in the following example:
privileges.Access['Global Answers']&& privileges.Access['Global Delivers']

I tried to use some variants of this, but all of this don't work (without privilege - link work)

```
14
<link id="l2" name="LinkName" description="LinkDesc" src="URL" target="blank" iconSmall="common/info_ena.png" >
       <privileges>
          <privilege.Access['Global Answers']/>
       </privileges>
       <locations>
          <location name="header" insertBefore="home"/>
       </locations>
    </link>
13  
    <link id="l2" name="LinkName" description="LinkDesc" src="URL" target="blank" iconSmall="common/info_ena.png" >
       <privileges>
          <privilege.Access['Global Answers']="true"/>
       </privileges>
       <locations>
          <location name="header" insertBefore="home"/>
       </locations>
    </link>
12
    <link id="l2" name="LinkName" description="LinkDesc" src="URL" target="blank" iconSmall="common/info_ena.png" privileges.Access['Global Answers']="true">
       <locations>
          <location name="header" insertBefore="home"/>
       </locations>
    </link>
11
    <link id="l2" name="LinkName" description="LinkDesc" src="URL" target="blank" iconSmall="common/info_ena.png" >
       <privilege>
          <privileges.Access['Global Answers']="true"/>
       </privilege>
       <locations>
          <location name="header" insertBefore="home"/>
       </locations>
    </link>
9
    <link id="l2" name="LinkName" description="LinkDesc" 
    src="URL" target="blank" iconSmall="common/info_ena.png" privileges.isAdmin = true>
       <locations>
          <location name="getstarted" />
       </locations>
    </link>
```

Comment: privileges.Access['Global Answers']&amp;&amp; privileges.Access['Global Delivers']

Answer (score 0):

1.) Don't repeat your link IDs. It's an ID and is supposed to be unique.

2.) The solution is

Privileges is an attribute of the link element. If you have any doubt it's always best to look into the .xsd for the xml file!

Comment: The second block of code - it's just lot of variants of 1 piece of code, so there are same ids.

Answer (score 0):

And now I have right decision:

```
<link id="l3" name="LinkName" description="Desc" src="URL" target="blank" iconSmall="common/info_ena.png" privilege = "privileges.Access['Global Admin']">
       <locations>
          <location name="header" insertBefore="home"/>
       </locations>
    </link>
```

Comment: That's what I posted 2 days ago